# What happened to the missiles of Tipu Sultan?

Tags: india

Why didn't anyone develop the missiles of [Tipu Sultan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tipu_Sultan) further?

Neither British nor Marathas?

Comment: What makes you think that the British didn't develop [them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Congreve_rocket)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The British did develop the technology further. Captured Mysorean rockets were returned to the UK, and the Royal Woolwich Arsenal started a [military rocket research and development program in 1801](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jkk5DAAAQBAJ&pg=PT81&lpg=PT81&dq=royal+woolwich+arsenal+rocket+1801&source=bl&ots=LFML5C3PJq&sig=75-L1HnLmZsYnOPKh1aqEU6B13U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiovsaExfrTAhUG1xoKHZ2lBqoQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=royal%20woolwich%20arsenal%20rocket%201801&f=false).